# Unable to render SVG path

Tags: html, svg

I am not sure why I am not able to display the SVG using the same path of the second SVG:

```html
<svg height="300" width="300">
  <path d="M 0.037 1.06c-0.01,0.001 -0.02,0.005 -0.026,0.011 -0.007,0.007 -0.011,0.016 -0.011,0.026l0 0.037 1.851 0 0 -0.037c0,-0.01 -0.004,-0.019 -0.01,-0.026 -0.007,-0.006 -0.016,-0.011 -0.027,-0.011l-0.592 0 -0.592 0 -0.593 0 0 0zm0.378 -0.533l0 0.074 0.074 0 0 -0.074 -0.074 0zm-0.237 0.074l0.074 0 0 -0.074 -0.074 0 0 0.074zm0.074 0.237l0 -0.074 -0.074 0 0 0.074 0.074 0zm0.237 0l0 -0.074 -0.074 0 0 0.074 0.074 0zm0.948 0l0 -0.074 -0.074 0 0 0.074 0.074 0zm0.237 -0.074l-0.074 0 0 0.074 0.074 0 0 -0.074zm-0.074 -0.237l0 0.074 0.074 0 0 -0.074 -0.074 0zm-0.237 0l0 0.074 0.074 0 0 -0.074 -0.074 0zm-0.119 -0.178l0 0.667 0.548 0 0 -0.667 -0.548 0zm0.096 0.371l0.119 0c0.012,0 0.022,0.01 0.022,0.022l0 0.118c0,0.013 -0.01,0.023 -0.022,0.023l-0.119 0c-0.012,0 -0.022,-0.01 -0.022,-0.023l0 -0.118c0,-0.012 0.01,-0.022 0.022,-0.022zm0.215 0.14l0 -0.118c0,-0.012 0.01,-0.022 0.022,-0.022l0.119 0c0.012,0 0.022,0.01 0.022,0.022l0 0.118c0,0.013 -0.01,0.023 -0.022,0.023l-0.119 0c-0.012,0 -0.022,-0.01 -0.022,-0.023zm0 -0.237l0 -0.118c0,-0.012 0.01,-0.022 0.022,-0.022l0.119 0c0.012,0 0.022,0.01 0.022,0.022l0 0.118c0,0.013 -0.01,0.023 -0.022,0.023l-0.119 0c-0.012,0 -0.022,-0.01 -0.022,-0.023zm-0.096 0.023l-0.119 0c-0.012,0 -0.022,-0.01 -0.022,-0.023l0 -0.118c0,-0.012 0.01,-0.022 0.022,-0.022l0.119 0c0.012,0 0.022,0.01 0.022,0.022l0 0.118c0,0.013 -0.01,0.023 -0.022,0.023zm-0.465 0.087c-0.018,-0.017 -0.042,-0.028 -0.068,-0.028 -0.027,0 -0.051,0.011 -0.068,0.028l-0.001 0.001c-0.017,0.018 -0.028,0.041 -0.028,0.067l0 0.215 0.193 0 0 -0.215c0,-0.026 -0.011,-0.05 -0.028,-0.068zm-0.002 -0.376c0,-0.019 -0.007,-0.035 -0.019,-0.047 -0.012,-0.012 -0.029,-0.02 -0.047,-0.02 -0.018,0 -0.035,0.007 -0.046,0.019l-0.001 0.001c-0.012,0.012 -0.02,0.028 -0.02,0.047 0,0.018 0.008,0.035 0.02,0.047 0.012,0.012 0.028,0.019 0.047,0.019 0.018,0 0.034,-0.007 0.046,-0.018l0.001 -0.001c0.012,-0.012 0.019,-0.029 0.019,-0.047zm0.145 -0.245l0.097 0.078c0.006,0.004 0.01,0.011 0.01,0.019l0 0.096 0.57 0 0.025 0 -0.092 -0.193 -0.61 0zm-0.485 0.107l0 0.108 0 0.689 0.133 0 0 -0.215c0,-0.038 0.015,-0.073 0.04,-0.098l0.001 -0.001c0.026,-0.026 0.061,-0.042 0.1,-0.042 0.038,0 0.074,0.016 0.099,0.042 0.026,0.025 0.041,0.06 0.041,0.099l0 0.215 0.134 0 0 -0.689 0 -0.108 -0.274 -0.219 -0.274 0.219zm0.197 0.058c0.02,-0.019 0.047,-0.031 0.077,-0.031 0.03,0 0.058,0.012 0.078,0.032 0.02,0.02 0.033,0.048 0.033,0.079 0,0.03 -0.013,0.058 -0.033,0.078l-0.001 0.002c-0.02,0.019 -0.047,0.031 -0.077,0.031 -0.031,0 -0.059,-0.013 -0.079,-0.033 -0.02,-0.02 -0.032,-0.048 -0.032,-0.078 0,-0.031 0.012,-0.059 0.032,-0.079l0.002 -0.001zm-0.812 0.028l0.57 0 0 -0.096 0 0c0,-0.007 0.003,-0.013 0.009,-0.018l0.098 -0.079 -0.61 0 -0.091 0.193 0.024 0zm0.022 0.711l0.548 0 0 -0.667 -0.548 0 0 0.667zm0.334 -0.133c-0.013,0 -0.023,-0.01 -0.023,-0.023l0 -0.118c0,-0.012 0.01,-0.022 0.023,-0.022l0.118 0c0.012,0 0.022,0.01 0.022,0.022l0 0.118c0,0.013 -0.01,0.023 -0.022,0.023l-0.118 0zm0.118 -0.237l-0.118 0c-0.013,0 -0.023,-0.01 -0.023,-0.023l0 -0.118c0,-0.012 0.01,-0.022 0.023,-0.022l0.118 0c0.012,0 0.022,0.01 0.022,0.022l0 0.118c0,0.013 -0.01,0.023 -0.022,0.023zm-0.237 0.237l-0.118 0c-0.013,0 -0.023,-0.01 -0.023,-0.023l0 -0.118c0,-0.012 0.01,-0.022 0.023,-0.022l0.118 0c0.012,0 0.022,0.01 0.022,0.022l0 0.118c0,0.013 -0.01,0.023 -0.022,0.023zm0 -0.237l-0.118 0c-0.013,0 -0.023,-0.01 -0.023,-0.023l0 -0.118c0,-0.012 0.01,-0.022 0.023,-0.022l0.118 0c0.012,0 0.022,0.01 0.022,0.022l0 0.118c0,0.013 -0.01,0.023 -0.022,0.023zZ" />
</svg>



<svg  viewBox="0 0 1.851 1.4175"><path  d="M0.037 1.06c-0.01,0.001 -0.02,0.005 -0.026,0.011 -0.007,0.007 -0.011,0.016 -0.011,0.026l0 0.037 1.851 0 0 -0.037c0,-0.01 -0.004,-0.019 -0.01,-0.026 -0.007,-0.006 -0.016,-0.011 -0.027,-0.011l-0.592 0 -0.592 0 -0.593 0 0 0zm0.378 -0.533l0 0.074 0.074 0 0 -0.074 -0.074 0zm-0.237 0.074l0.074 0 0 -0.074 -0.074 0 0 0.074zm0.074 0.237l0 -0.074 -0.074 0 0 0.074 0.074 0zm0.237 0l0 -0.074 -0.074 0 0 0.074 0.074 0zm0.948 0l0 -0.074 -0.074 0 0 0.074 0.074 0zm0.237 -0.074l-0.074 0 0 0.074 0.074 0 0 -0.074zm-0.074 -0.237l0 0.074 0.074 0 0 -0.074 -0.074 0zm-0.237 0l0 0.074 0.074 0 0 -0.074 -0.074 0zm-0.119 -0.178l0 0.667 0.548 0 0 -0.667 -0.548 0zm0.096 0.371l0.119 0c0.012,0 0.022,0.01 0.022,0.022l0 0.118c0,0.013 -0.01,0.023 -0.022,0.023l-0.119 0c-0.012,0 -0.022,-0.01 -0.022,-0.023l0 -0.118c0,-0.012 0.01,-0.022 0.022,-0.022zm0.215 0.14l0 -0.118c0,-0.012 0.01,-0.022 0.022,-0.022l0.119 0c0.012,0 0.022,0.01 0.022,0.022l0 0.118c0,0.013 -0.01,0.023 -0.022,0.023l-0.119 0c-0.012,0 -0.022,-0.01 -0.022,-0.023zm0 -0.237l0 -0.118c0,-0.012 0.01,-0.022 0.022,-0.022l0.119 0c0.012,0 0.022,0.01 0.022,0.022l0 0.118c0,0.013 -0.01,0.023 -0.022,0.023l-0.119 0c-0.012,0 -0.022,-0.01 -0.022,-0.023zm-0.096 0.023l-0.119 0c-0.012,0 -0.022,-0.01 -0.022,-0.023l0 -0.118c0,-0.012 0.01,-0.022 0.022,-0.022l0.119 0c0.012,0 0.022,0.01 0.022,0.022l0 0.118c0,0.013 -0.01,0.023 -0.022,0.023zm-0.465 0.087c-0.018,-0.017 -0.042,-0.028 -0.068,-0.028 -0.027,0 -0.051,0.011 -0.068,0.028l-0.001 0.001c-0.017,0.018 -0.028,0.041 -0.028,0.067l0 0.215 0.193 0 0 -0.215c0,-0.026 -0.011,-0.05 -0.028,-0.068zm-0.002 -0.376c0,-0.019 -0.007,-0.035 -0.019,-0.047 -0.012,-0.012 -0.029,-0.02 -0.047,-0.02 -0.018,0 -0.035,0.007 -0.046,0.019l-0.001 0.001c-0.012,0.012 -0.02,0.028 -0.02,0.047 0,0.018 0.008,0.035 0.02,0.047 0.012,0.012 0.028,0.019 0.047,0.019 0.018,0 0.034,-0.007 0.046,-0.018l0.001 -0.001c0.012,-0.012 0.019,-0.029 0.019,-0.047zm0.145 -0.245l0.097 0.078c0.006,0.004 0.01,0.011 0.01,0.019l0 0.096 0.57 0 0.025 0 -0.092 -0.193 -0.61 0zm-0.485 0.107l0 0.108 0 0.689 0.133 0 0 -0.215c0,-0.038 0.015,-0.073 0.04,-0.098l0.001 -0.001c0.026,-0.026 0.061,-0.042 0.1,-0.042 0.038,0 0.074,0.016 0.099,0.042 0.026,0.025 0.041,0.06 0.041,0.099l0 0.215 0.134 0 0 -0.689 0 -0.108 -0.274 -0.219 -0.274 0.219zm0.197 0.058c0.02,-0.019 0.047,-0.031 0.077,-0.031 0.03,0 0.058,0.012 0.078,0.032 0.02,0.02 0.033,0.048 0.033,0.079 0,0.03 -0.013,0.058 -0.033,0.078l-0.001 0.002c-0.02,0.019 -0.047,0.031 -0.077,0.031 -0.031,0 -0.059,-0.013 -0.079,-0.033 -0.02,-0.02 -0.032,-0.048 -0.032,-0.078 0,-0.031 0.012,-0.059 0.032,-0.079l0.002 -0.001zm-0.812 0.028l0.57 0 0 -0.096 0 0c0,-0.007 0.003,-0.013 0.009,-0.018l0.098 -0.079 -0.61 0 -0.091 0.193 0.024 0zm0.022 0.711l0.548 0 0 -0.667 -0.548 0 0 0.667zm0.334 -0.133c-0.013,0 -0.023,-0.01 -0.023,-0.023l0 -0.118c0,-0.012 0.01,-0.022 0.023,-0.022l0.118 0c0.012,0 0.022,0.01 0.022,0.022l0 0.118c0,0.013 -0.01,0.023 -0.022,0.023l-0.118 0zm0.118 -0.237l-0.118 0c-0.013,0 -0.023,-0.01 -0.023,-0.023l0 -0.118c0,-0.012 0.01,-0.022 0.023,-0.022l0.118 0c0.012,0 0.022,0.01 0.022,0.022l0 0.118c0,0.013 -0.01,0.023 -0.022,0.023zm-0.237 0.237l-0.118 0c-0.013,0 -0.023,-0.01 -0.023,-0.023l0 -0.118c0,-0.012 0.01,-0.022 0.023,-0.022l0.118 0c0.012,0 0.022,0.01 0.022,0.022l0 0.118c0,0.013 -0.01,0.023 -0.022,0.023zm0 -0.237l-0.118 0c-0.013,0 -0.023,-0.01 -0.023,-0.023l0 -0.118c0,-0.012 0.01,-0.022 0.023,-0.022l0.118 0c0.012,0 0.022,0.01 0.022,0.022l0 0.118c0,0.013 -0.01,0.023 -0.022,0.023z"/>/svg>
```

**[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/BhZjV/863/)**

Comment: Because the entire path is drawn within 2 units, and you haven't specified the `viewBox` on the first SVG so it's defaulting to 2px - hence the tiny black dot in the top-left.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your missing the view box.

```html
<svg  viewBox="0 0 1.851 1.4175"> path </svg>
```

Comment: but I do not want a View box. I want to pass the values in Javascript Path option